# Spellathon solver in Java

Tags: java

[What is Spellathon?](http://scrabblewordfinders.net/spellathon/)

The rules of Spellathon are as follows:

- Create words that have 4 to 7 letters.
- Include the center letter in every word.
- Form at least one 7-letter word.
- Plurals are acceptable.
- The dictionary used is in English.

[Here](http://spellathon.sourceforge.net/) is a similar implementation.

The dictionary (word list) I'm using is [this](https://github.com/dwyl/english-words).

```
public class Spellathon {

    private static final Set<String> permutations = new HashSet<>();

    private static void permutation(String str) {
        permutation(str.charAt(0), "", str);
    }

    private static void permutation(char idx, String prefix, String str) {
        int n = str.length();

        if (n != 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                permutation(idx, prefix + str.charAt(i), str.substring(0, i) + str.substring(i + 1, n));
            }
        }

        if(prefix.length() > 3 && prefix.indexOf(idx) >= 0) {
            permutations.add(prefix);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String letters;

        System.out.print("Input: ");
        letters = sc.nextLine();

        permutation(letters);

        try {
            for(String x: permutations) {
                Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));

                while(scFile.hasNextLine()) {
                    String cur = scFile.nextLine();
                    if(cur.equalsIgnoreCase(x)) {
                        System.out.println("Found: " + cur);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            System.out.println("Word list file Not Found.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Input:** Pass the given letters as a String with the central letter as the first letter. The other letters can be in any order.

**Output:**

```
Input: elolh
Found: Hell
Found: hell
Found: Lole
Found: hello
Found: Holle
Found: Hole
Found: hole
```

I don't mind the redundant occurrences. My issue is that the code takes a lot of time to execute (that is why, I used 5 letters as an example).

Any comments/answers that can help reduce the execution time will be appreciated. Also, if anyone review the overall correctness of the program, it will be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The explanation for slowness is simple: you're doing a slow operation (reading a file) many many times (due to combinatorial explosion).

How many permutations of "hello" are there? For 5 items, there are 5!, or 120 permutations. However, two of the letters are indistinguishable, so it's actually \$\frac{5!}{2!}\$, or 60. Add the 12 permutations of "hell", 24 permutations of "helo", and 12 permutations of "hllo", and we have about a hundred.

Of those, I would expect only maybe a dozen to be valid English words.

Then, for each permutation, you are opening the file and reading every line to see if the candidate is a word. File IO involves the operating system and the disk — both very expensive.

---

Generating all permutations of something is costly. In contrast, checking whether two given words are permutations of each other is a simple matter of counting.

A smarter approach, therefore, would be to go through the dictionary once, and check whether each word meets the acceptance criteria.

Comment: "[T]he 12 permutations of 'hell'" sounds like the title of book.

Answer (score 3):

#### Don't read the file multiple times

> ```
>         try {
>             for(String x: permutations) {
>                 Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"));
>
>                 while(scFile.hasNextLine()) {
>                     String cur = scFile.nextLine();
>                     if(cur.equalsIgnoreCase(x)) {
>                         System.out.println("Found: " + cur);
>                     }
>                 }
>             }
> ```

You don't need to create a new `Scanner` on every iteration of a loop.  Consider

```
        try (Scanner scFile = new Scanner(new File("words.txt"))) {
            while (scFile.hasNextLine()) {
                String word = scFile.nextLine().toLowerCase();
                if (permutations.contains(word)) {
                    System.out.println("Found: " + word);
                }
            }
```

The [`try`-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) form will automatically close the `Scanner` for you when finished.  Even if an exception is thrown.

Then you just need to change

> ```
>         permutation(letters);
> ```

to

```
        permutation(letters.toLowerCase());
```

and you can take advantage of the quick access time of `HashSet`.

Note that you could also use a custom type with case insensitive `equals` and `hashCode` methods instead of taking `toLowerCase` on `letters` and the words in the file.

#### Separate logic and display

Rather than printing the string, consider saving it instead:

```
                if (permutations.contains(word)) {
                    words.add(word);
                }
```

And declare

```
        List<String> words = new ArrayList<>();
```

#### Don't mix delegation and logic

You delegate to `permutations` and then you check them in `main`.  Delegate the checking.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String letters = sc.nextLine().toLowerCase();

            permutation(letters);

            for (String word : findWordsInPermutations()) {
                System.out.println("Found: " + word);
            }
        }
    }
```

This way `main` only handles standard input and output.

Note that `permutation` and `findWordsInPermutations` would be more flexible if they were `static` and returned `permutations` and took `permutations` as a parameter respectively.

#### You can do better

Rather than generating permutations, test each word in the dictionary against the input.

Change

```
                if (permutations.contains(word)) {
```

to

```
                if (isPermutation(word, letters)) {
```

Then just define `isPermutation` such that it returns `true` if and only if `word` can be made from `letters`.

Then you don't need the `permutation` method at all.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in other answers, the best way to improve the performance is to read the dictionary only once. For a decent sized dictionary, the difference in performance will be huge.

This is an alternative approach reading each word in the dictionary and checking if it is a permutation of the given letters:

```
public class Spellathon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.print("Input: ");
            String letters = sc.nextLine();
            permutationsOf(letters, "words.txt").forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open the file");
        }
    }

    public static List<String> permutationsOf(String letters, String file) throws IOException{
        List<Character> letterList = new ArrayList<>(letters.length());
        for (char c : letters.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            letterList.add(c);
        }
        try (Stream<String> words = Files.lines(Paths.get(file));) {
            return words.filter(word->word.length() <= letters.length())
                        .filter(word->isPermutation(word, letterList))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
        } 
    }

    public static boolean isPermutation(String word, List<Character> letterList) {
        List<Character> remainingLetters = new ArrayList<Character>(letterList);
        for (char letter : word.toLowerCase().toCharArray()) {
            if (!remainingLetters.remove(Character.valueOf(letter))) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```